# sort an nsdictionary based on object(actually keys) of another array

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a an `NSArray` named `self.ownerOrderArray`, which logs like this:

```
order array is (
"Date Of Birth",
republic,
Marriage,
Currency,
Incentive,
"Interview Dates",
hobbies,
"Tanki Online",
skills,
"Sal Range"
)
```

I also have an `NSMutableDictionary` as  `self.tempDict` Which logs:

logs like this:

```
tempDict dictionary is>>>>> {
Currency = 56789;
"Date Of Birth" = "2014-03-15";
Incentive = 5;
"Interview Dates" = "Jan 20";
Marriage = "2014-03-29";
"Sal Range" = "|#|0 - 10k|#|10k - 20k|#|20k -30k|#|30k-40k|#|40k-50k|#|";
"Tanki Online" = Thunder;
hobbies = Cricket;
republic = 26jan;
skills = "|#|PHP|#|Java|#|Python|#|objctive-c|#|c|#|c++|#|objective-c++|#|c#|#|";
}
```

How can I get the above dictionary whose key/values are sorted in the same order as `self.ownerOrderArray`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a dictionary which logs the values in the same order because a dictionary does not have an order.

What you can do is to get an array of values which match the order of your array of keys using `objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:`. If you have all of the keys then the not found marker isn't an issue, just set it to `[NSNull null]`. If you don't have all the keys then you need to watch out for nulls in the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

As per Wain , "you can't get a dictionary which logs the values in the same order as you given".

You first sort the all keys by ascending or descending order of a dictionary, after that you fetch the values on sorted array keys index. like this

```
NSDictionary *valuesDictionary = //Your Response Dictionary ;

NSArray *sortedKeys = [[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];

NSMutableDictionary *orderedDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSString *key in sortedKeys){
            [orderedDictionary setObject:[valuesDictionary objectForKey: key] forKey:key];
}
```

Should this work for you.